# group by results sets in one row ms access query

Tags: sql, ms-access, excel, vba

I need help with ms access query. My current group by is adding additional rows with my result sets.

currently it is this:

```
schoolsName organization    city    agent   total   organization_award  city_award  agent_award
John Boscoe 0   0   2   2           10000
John Boscoe 0   26  0   26      1000    
John Boscoe 0   2   2   2       4000    100000
John Boscoe 18  0   0   18  10000       
John Boscoe 3   3   0   3   5000    10000
```

my current sql query for ms access is:

```
SELECT 
schools.schoolsName, Count(schools.[organization]) AS organization, 
Count(schools.[city]) AS city, Count(schools.[agent]) AS agent, 
Count(schools.schoolsName) AS total, 
IIf((schools.[organization]) Like 'yes',Sum(schools.[dollaramount]),'') AS organization_award, 
IIf((schools.[city]) Like 'yes',Sum(schools.[dollaramount]),'') AS city_award, 
IIf((schools.[agent]) Like 'yes',Sum(schools.[dollaramount]),'') AS agent_award
FROM schools
GROUP BY schools.schoolsName, schools.[organization], schools.[city], schools.[agent];
```

how do i change the above query to get this result set:

```
schoolsName organization    city    agent   total   organization_award  city_award  agent_award
John Boscoe 21  31  4   51  15000   15000   110000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure about the count part, but did you try this?

```
    SELECT schools.schoolsName, 
           Count(schools.[organization]) AS organization, 
           Count(schools.[city]) AS city, 
           Count(schools.[agent]) AS agent, 
           Count(schools.schoolsName) AS total, 
           Sum(IIf((schools.[organization]) Like 'yes', schools.[dollaramount],0)) AS organization_award, 
           Sum(IIf((schools.[city]) Like 'yes', schools.[dollaramount],0)) AS city_award, 
           Sum(IIf((schools.[agent]) Like 'yes', schools.[dollaramount],0)) AS agent_award
      FROM schools
  GROUP BY schools.schoolsName;
```

Comment: sweet this works. i used this group by "GROUP BY schools.schoolsName"